# Trouble Implementing a BoxInterface for Gtk4 in Rust

Tags: rust, gtk4

I've been working on a project involving GTK4, and I'm trying to implement a BoxInterface trait to wrap a GTK4 Box. However, my current implementation seems to be causing issues, and I'm struggling to figure out why.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```rust
use gtk4::prelude::*;
use std::boxed::Box;

use std::any::Any;
pub trait BoxInterface: Any {
    fn push_back(&mut self, child: Box<dyn BoxInterface>);
}

pub struct GtkBox {
    box_widget: gtk4::Box,
}

impl GtkBox {
    pub fn new(box_widget: gtk4::Box) -> Self {
        GtkBox {
            box_widget
        }
    }
}

impl BoxInterface for GtkBox {
    fn push_back(&mut self, child: Box<dyn BoxInterface>) {
        if let Ok(gtk_box) = child.downcast::<Box<GtkBox>>() {
            self.box_widget.append(&gtk_box.box_widget);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
}
```

My goal is to  create box interface type and have a GTK box implementation for it (and some other GUI library in future) . However, I'm encountering issues with downcasting.

The code works when push_back interface passes `Box<dyn Any>` but I'd like to have the extra type safety with the interface trait.

Could someone please help me understand what might be going wrong here? Additionally, if you have any suggestions on how to fix this code or a better approach to achieve my goal, I would greatly appreciate it!

Attempted to downcast `Box<dyn BoxInterface>` to `Box<GtkBox>` Expected it to work, instead got compile error

```
error[E0599]: the method `downcast` exists for struct `Box<dyn BoxInterface>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:23:36
    |
5   |   pub trait BoxInterface: Any {
    |   ---------------------------
    |   |
    |   doesn't satisfy `dyn BoxInterface: ObjectType`
    |   doesn't satisfy `dyn BoxInterface: Sized`
    |   doesn't satisfy `dyn BoxInterface: gtk4::prelude::Cast`
...
23  |           if let Ok(gtk_box) = child.downcast::<Box<GtkBox>>() {
    |                                      ^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `Box<dyn BoxInterface>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
```

Comment: [`downcast` is implemented on `Box<dyn Any>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.downcast), `Box<dyn BoxInterface>` as a different type, so it has no `downcast` method.